# Convert factor to numeric in data frame

Tags: r

For some of functions which I would like to introduce to my data I need a numeric values in my data frame. Now they are in factor format.

Is there any easy way to "transform" whole data frame into a numeric ?

Part of 'dput':

```
"0.966968221", "0.971526427", "0.975908363", "0.976354638", 
    "0.983503732", "0.984850291", "0.985224666", "0.987182132", 
    "0.987468192", "0.988309086", "0.994685984", "0.996238630", 
    "0.997917853", "0.998762891", "0.999968143", "1.000000000"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("10", "33.95", "58.66", 
"84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1", "234.35", "257.19", 
"361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71", "732.59", "817.56", 
"896.24", "971.77", "1038.91"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", 
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01320.2", "at1g01470.1", "at1g01800.1"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Class of values in data.frame:

```
> class(tbl_alles[103,5])
[1] "factor"
> class(tbl_alles[553,12])
[1] "factor"
```

What I've tried so far:

First try:

```
tbl_alles <- sapply(tbl_alles, as.numeric) ## Changing the values in the data frame
```

Second try:

```
> as.numeric(as.character(tbl_alles))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Third try:

```
 > as.numeric(levels(tbl_alles))[tbl_alles]
Error in as.numeric(levels(tbl_alles))[tbl_alles] : 
  invalid subscript type 'list
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
tbl_alles[sapply(tbl_alles, is.factor)] <- lapply(tbl_alles[sapply(tbl_alles, is.factor)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

This function will look up columns of type `factor` and convert them to class `numeric`

Another option (maybe a bit faster) is using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl_alles)[, names(tbl_alles) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x)]
```

If your whole data set is of type `factor` and you want to transfer **all** the columns to `numeric` type, you could do

```
tbl_alles[] <- lapply(tbl_alles, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: +1, For the last case, I would also use: tbl_alles[] <- lapply(tbl_alles, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

Comment: @akrun, Great suggestion. I always forget the `[]` keeping the format thing :). Edited

Comment: The last one works perfect for me. I didn't take a look on the others but thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver, you should probably use the others as part of your tools kit (I do). You can also use them as refactoring function in situations when you've subseted a data set and you have lots of variables with empty factors, you could `tbl_alles[sapply(tbl_alles, is.factor)] <- lapply(tbl_alles[sapply(tbl_alles, is.factor)], factor)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. This function is really usefull if you are not sure that your data includes only factors but in that case I was that's why I used the last one. Anyway, your reply for my question is really clear and helpful for many people.